# hover div makes title appear above section

Tags: html, css

I have different sections on my website and when hovering those section (first-article-block) I wish their title show on the top of those section, but not while hovering the entire div, just the block

also while the title is hidden, it takes space and not letting my section to be right in the middle

Here is the code

thank you

```css
.first-article {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.first-article-title {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.first-article-block {
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.first-article-block:hover + .first-article-title {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="article col-md-12">
      <div class="first-article col-md-4 col-xs-12">
         <h2 class="first-article-title">My first article</h2>
         <div class="first-article-block">
            <div class="content"> </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `first-article-title` is BEFORE `first-article-block` so you can't use css selectors for that need to change html structure or use javascript. CSS goes only DOWN the HTML structure . not up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: you can put the hidden element inside the container and use absolute position to set it's position:

```css
.first-article {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.first-article-title {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.first-article-block {
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.first-article-block:hover .first-article-title {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="article col-md-12">
      <div class="first-article col-md-4 col-xs-12">
         <div class="first-article-block">
            <h2 class="first-article-title">My first article</h2>
            <div class="content"> </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Option 2: use javascript for that:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.first-article-block').hover(function() {
    $('.first-article-title').css({'visibility': 'visible', 'opacity': 1});
  }, function() {
    $('.first-article-title').css({'visibility': 'hidden', 'opacity': 0});
  });
});
```

```css
.first-article {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.first-article-title {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.first-article-block {
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="article col-md-12">
      <div class="first-article col-md-4 col-xs-12">
         <h2 class="first-article-title">My first article</h2>
         <div class="first-article-block">
            <div class="content"> </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and your explanation. I would like only to make it in CSS, javascript is nice but maybe too much for a simple thing like that and couldn't figure out how to make it work, I will try the css version of it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, no need jquery or javascript

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="article col-md-12">
            <div class="first-article col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="first-article-block">
                    <div class="content">
                    test
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h2 class="first-article-title">My first article</h2>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.first-article {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.first-article-title {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    visibility: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    padding:0;
    margin:-50px;
}

.first-article-block {
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
}

div.first-article-block:hover + h2 {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Hop this help you

Answer (score 0):

`first-article-title` is BEFORE `first-article-block` so you can't use CSS selectors for that need to change html structure or use JavaScript. CSS goes only DOWN the HTML structure, not up.

The first solution would be to change the HTML and CSS a bit .

Put the title inside `first-article-block` but before the `content` .

Add the CSS styles you set for `first-article-block` to `content` instead. and you will get the desired result

```css
.first-article {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.first-article-title {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.first-article-block .content{
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.first-article-block:hover .first-article-title {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="article col-md-12">
            <div class="first-article col-md-4 col-xs-12">
           
                <div class="first-article-block">
                 <h2 class="first-article-title">My first article</h2>
                    <div class="content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time showing me this, I will try and apply it. I forgot the basic rule of css going down html. I will try your version, didn't thought about risizing my content either

Comment: you don't need to resize the content . you just have to 'move' the styles from `.first-article-block` to `.first-article-block .content` and move `first-article-title` inside `.first-article-block` but before `.content` so title and content are siblings

Comment: yes, but the title appear even when i'm not hovering the block, I would have like to make it appear only when the blue block is hovered